# Swift ios unwind to root ViewController tab from anywhere

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a tab based app. And I wonder if its possible to unwind the user from anywhere to the root of the current tab.

My app is built like this: TabController -> (tabs) -> navigationController -> vc etc..

So lets say that I press on tab 4 in my app. Now I dig through two viewcontrollers and end up in a modal presented VC. Now I want to go back straight to the root of the tab:

tab 4 -> navigationController -> **rootVC** -> **pushVC** -> **pushVC** -> **modalVc**

So I eg from **modalVc** to **rootVC**

I know that I can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them), BUT I want to go to the rootVC from any VC within tab4, and using that technique would force me to create a unwind segue on all of my child VCs in tab 4

I am using notifications and when a user press on the notification I want to take the user to the rootVC from anywhere.

And using something like:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "accountVc") as? AccountViewController
                      navInTab.pushViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: false)
```

Does not work for eg: vc -> vc -> modalVc

since it will mess up the navigationstack

Comment: Exactly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Joe that does not work with modal VC for me

Answer (score 0):

You can pop to the root of a navigation stack, or pop to the nth element in the stack, or replace the stack of view controllers with a different stack.

You can use `popToRootViewController` on the navigationController to go back to the very root of a navigation stack. Or suppose you want to go back to the first VC in the stack for example, you would do something like

```
let controllerStack = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
_ = self.navigationController?.popToViewController((controllerStack?[0])!, animated: true)
```

Or you can replace the navigation stack of view controllers with a new stack of controllers i.e.

```
NSMutableArray *controllerStack = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:navigationController.viewControllers];
// Replace the source controller with the destination controller, wherever the source may be
[controllerStack replaceObjectAtIndex:[controllerStack indexOfObject:sourceViewController] withObject:destinationController];

// Assign the updated stack with animation
[navigationController setViewControllers:controllerStack animated:YES];
```

Comment: Trying to use your first example I get the error: Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for App

Comment: And could you provide a swift example of the second?